# HTMLParser. Parse but result is empty

Tags: objective-c, ios, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse [this page](https://www.deutsche-bank-pbc.pl/index.php/l1/kursy_walut) with HTMLParser. Work with columns: "waluta", "kupno" and "sprzedaż".
My code:

```
NSError * error = nil;
HTMLParser * parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.deutsche-bank-pbc.pl/index.php/l1/kursy_walut"] error:&error];   
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    parser = nil;
    return;
}
NSLog(@"parser = %@", parser);
HTMLNode * bodyNode = [parser doc]; // получаем родительский элемент

HTMLNode *mynode = [bodyNode findChildWithAttribute:@"id" matchingName:@"container_c" allowPartial:NO]; // Берем div с id="all"
HTMLNode *mynode2 = [mynode findChildTag:@"table"];

NSArray *newsList = [mynode2 findChildrenOfClass:@"table_td_1"];
NSLog(@"newsList = %@",newsList];
for (HTMLNode *news in newsList) {
    NSLog(@"element = %@",[news allContents] );
}
```

First NSLog shows filled NSArray with HTMLNode objects. But NSLog in my loop shows empty elements:

```
2012-05-31 13:10:31.981 [11178:f803] element = 
2012-05-31 13:10:31.982 [11178:f803] element = 
2012-05-31 13:10:31.983 [11178:f803] element = 
2012-05-31 13:10:31.983 [11178:f803] element =
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about HTMLParser,
But why don't you use WebView and once document loaded, access all the property / attribute through its dom element,
Need not to load them on the UI , but i am quite sure, this approach will work.